# Conditional Calculation for a Column in R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
pop.2017 <- c(434,346,345,357)
pop.2018 <- c(334,336,325,345)
pop.2019 <- c(477,346,145,345)
pop.2020 <- c(474,366,341,300)


total <- c(34,36,34,35)


incident_month_yr <- c("2017-2","2017-5","2018-2","2019-2")

df <- data.frame(incident_month_yr,pop.2017,pop.2018,pop.2019,pop.2020,total)

df['perc'] <- NA
```

For rows where incident_month_yr contains 2017, I want `perc` to equal `total/pop.2017`
For rows where incident_month_yr contains 2018, I want `perc` to equal `total/pop.2018`
For rows where incident_month_yr contains 2019, I want `perc` to equal `total/pop.2019`
For rows where incident_month_yr contains 2020, I want `perc` to equal `total/pop.2020`

I've tried this:

```
df$perc[grepl(2017,df$incident_month_yr)] <- df$total/df$pop.2017
df$perc[grepl(2018,df$incident_month_yr)] <- df$total/df$pop.2018
df$perc[grepl(2019,df$incident_month_yr)] <- df$total/df$pop.2019
df$perc[grepl(2020,df$incident_month_yr)] <- df$total/df$pop.2020
```

However, it's not applying the calculations to specific rows like I want.  How can I do this?

Comment: Your table is in wide form, which is optimal for "human use", but not so much for "machine use". I would recommend that you store and process your data in long form and use wide form only for viewing purposes. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format, data.table::melt and dcast and tidyr::pivot_longer and pivot_wider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


df %>% 
  mutate(perc = ifelse(str_detect(incident_month_yr, "2017"), total/pop.2017, 
                       ifelse(str_detect(incident_month_yr, "2018"), total/pop.2018, 
                       total/pop.2019)))


  incident_month_yr pop.2017 pop.2018 pop.2019 pop.2020 total       perc
1            2017-2      434      334      477      474    34 0.07834101
2            2017-5      346      336      346      366    36 0.10404624
3            2018-2      345      325      145      341    34 0.10461538
4            2019-2      357      345      345      300    35 0.10144928
```

**Special Thanks** to dear @akrun
We can also replace `str_detect` with `grepl` function from base R to use fewer packages and use `case_when` in place of `ifelse` as an unnested alternative.

```
df %>%
  mutate(perc = case_when(
    grepl("2017", incident_month_yr) ~ total/pop.2017,
    grepl("2018", incident_month_yr) ~ total/pop.2018,
    TRUE ~ total/pop.2019
  ))

  incident_month_yr pop.2017 pop.2018 pop.2019 pop.2020 total       perc
1            2017-2      434      334      477      474    34 0.07834101
2            2017-5      346      336      346      366    36 0.10404624
3            2018-2      345      325      145      341    34 0.10461538
4            2019-2      357      345      345      300    35 0.10144928
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `match`.  Get the column names that have 'pop' substring ('nm1)',  remove the characters that are not year from 'incident_month_yr', and the column name, use `match` to return the column index, `cbind` with the sequence of rows, extract the values from the 'pop' columns, divide by 'total' and assign it to 'perc' column

```
nm1 <- grep('pop', names(df), value = TRUE)
nm2 <- trimws(df$incident_month_yr, whitespace = '-.*')
nm3 <- trimws(nm1, whitespace = 'pop\\.')
df$perc <- df$total/df[nm1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), match(nm2, nm3))]
df$perc
#[1] 0.07834101 0.10404624 0.10461538 0.10144928
```

---

In `dplyr`, an option is do `rowwise`, construct the column name from the 'incident_month_yr' with `str_replace` to capture the year part, append the 'pop.' as prefix, `get` the value and divide with 'total' column

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(perc = total/get(str_replace(incident_month_yr,
           "(\\d{4})-\\d+", 'pop.\\1'))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  incident_month_yr pop.2017 pop.2018 pop.2019 pop.2020 total   perc
#  <chr>                <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 2017-2                 434      334      477      474    34 0.0783
#2 2017-5                 346      336      346      366    36 0.104 
#3 2018-2                 345      325      145      341    34 0.105 
#4 2019-2                 357      345      345      300    35 0.101
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun!  I have no do doubt your solution works, my mind just finds ifelse statements easier to comprehend.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches, one in base R and one using tidy data. The provided data is not tidy, that's why base R looks uncomfortable:

```r
# Define the target
target <- c(0.07834101, 0.10404624, 0.10461538, 0.10144928)
```

That is our goal, calculating `target`.

First, use base R and `ifelse`:

```r
result1 <- with(df, 
                ifelse(grepl(2017, incident_month_yr),
                       total/pop.2017,
                       ifelse(grepl(2018, incident_month_yr),
                              total/pop.2018,
                              ifelse(grepl(2019, incident_month_yr),
                                     total/pop.2019,
                                     ifelse(grepl(2020, incident_month_yr),
                                            total/pop.2020,
                                            NA)))))

identical(round(result1, 4), round(target, 4))
#> [1] TRUE
```

And, the tidy way, reshaping into [tidy data](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-data.html) and calculating the result:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(starts_with("pop."), names_to = "pop", names_prefix = "pop.") %>% 
  filter(substr(incident_month_yr, 1, 4) == pop) %>% 
  mutate(perc = total/value) %>% 
  pull(perc)

identical(round(result2, 4), round(target, 4))
#> [1] TRUE
```